# iOS, full screen image falls short on 4

Tags: ios

I am using an image as the full view background image. The image is provided in @2x (750 X 1334) & @3x (1242 X 2208). 
When i simulate on 5 & 4S it all appears fine, however i have executed the app on a real device, iPhone 4. It appears as if the image falls short of the top. I am using Scale to fit mode on the view which according to apple, should rescale the image to the window frame of the device.

[image: iPhone 4]

[image: iPhone 5]

[image: iPhone 4s]

Is this a image resolution issue, or is there additional work to support the iPhone 4?

Comment: Can you try to resize your `ImageView` frame to (0, 0, device width, device Height)

Comment: Are you using `UIImageView`? Why don't just use `self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"my-image"]];`

Comment: I am using storyboard for the background image currently but will try it out using code method. (would make sense as the background image is the only thing i've used storybook for - aside from the view controller)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`self.view.layer.contents = (id) [UIImage imageNamed:@"Launch Image.png"].CGImage;`

Im not sure why setting the image using Storyboard caused the offset for the iPhone 4 but i was able to resolve the issue using the line of code above.

I have to admit, CALayers are going to come in handy